# Oracle APEX GANTT Chart - additional label/columns behind the first

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a vacation planning in Oracle APEX via a GANTT chart.

I need additional columns behind the label (similar to a grid) for information at the corresponding employee/resource (free vacation days for example).

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or how can I implement this. Unfortunately I could not find a way to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you will have to use a composite JET component similar to the cookbook example: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=dataCollections&demo=withTable